# PHP Login Code Not Working - Forms And TXT File Saving

Tags: php, forms, authentication, txt

Storing passwords in a flat file is a non-negotiable requirement of my project.

I have been trying to make a system that allows users to signup and login using their username and password. (passwords are hashed and salted)

So far, I've completed the signup system and I'm trying to finish the login system, however my PHP code is not working.

Here's an example of how I store the passwords in the flat file:

```
UsernameHere,DOUBLEHASHEDPASSWORDHERE
--------------------
Username2Here,DOUBLEHASHEDPASSWORD2HERE
--------------------
```

Here's my Login PHP code:

```
<?php
$myFile = "/authentication/signup/accounts.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($myFile);
$contents = explode("\n", $contents);

foreach($contents as $values){
    $loginInfo = explode(",", $values);
    $user = $loginInfo[0];
    $password = $loginInfo[1];

    if($user == $_POST['username'] && $password == $_POST['password']){
        session_start(); 
        header('Location: /authentication/login/data=success');
    } else{;
        echo '<script>alert("Please verify your username and password.");</script>';
    };
};
?>
```

Here's the HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<p class="center">
<label for="username">Username</label><br />
<input type="text" name="username"></input></p>
<p class="center"><label for="password">Password</label><br />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-xlarge"></input></p>

<br />

<p class="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="submitsignupbtn"></input></p>
</form>
```

When I go to the login page it just redirects me to the successful login page, which means something isn't right here, as I haven't entered any credentials yet.

Comment: Check to see if you have a redirect on the form page if they're already logged in. Apparently it thinks it is

Comment: `$_POST['password']` has obviously NOT been DOUBLEHASHED as it is User Input so this `if($user == $_POST['username'] && $password == $_POST['password']){` line will NEVER Work

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us. Thanks.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing.
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users. And `password_hash()` provides it own STRONG Salt, another benefit

Comment: As a temporary test, add `echo "$user == {$_POST['username']} && $password == {$_POST['password']}";` inside of your if check to see the values being passed in. You really only should be doing that check when `$_POST` has been submitted instead of always

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for the response, I am using PHP's password hashing system in the signup code. ```$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  $double_hashed_password = password_hash($hashed_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);```

Comment: Ok, so that means you probably cannot use the `password_verify()` function because of the double hashing, I think you shot yourself in the foot basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to STOP double hashing the users password in the registration phase, as that stops you using the features provided in `password_verify()`.

Example coded here if you want a increase the hash strength, but  be aware that will take longer to run that hashing algo.

```
// Plain text password
$in_pass = 'The quick brown fox';

$options = ['cost' => 16];  

$hash = password_hash($in_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
echo $hash.PHP_EOL;
```

The hash, notice the COST is part of the resulting hash

```
$2y$16$xS/tLNvfqfFfWHSWFiQ04eKgTWcoKxz.HV1UfH8UO2A6.1VUuAQeK
   ^^^ this is the cost
```

> Small note you wont get the same hash as this, even if you use the same password

**So now your password check can use the features provided by PHP**

```
/*
* THis will only work if you remove the DOUBLEHASHING
*/
$myFile = "accounts.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($myFile);
$contents = explode("\n", $contents);

foreach($contents as $values){
    $loginInfo = explode(",", $values);
    $user = $loginInfo[0];
    if ( $user != $_POST['username']) {
        continue; // dont waste time if its not the same username, just go to next in loop
    }
    
    // get hashed password from the current record from file
    $hashedPwd = $loginInfo[1];

    if( password_verify( $_POST['password'], $hashedPwd ) ) {
        session_start();    // not sure what this is achieving as you are redirecting and not useing the session
        header('Location: /authentication/login/data=success');
        exit;
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("Please verify your username and password.");</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey there! I'm sorry for a response almost a year later but I've ran into a problem similar to this today and I would like to thank you for the clear comment. I have marked your answer a solution! Have a nice day/night!

It worked like a charm by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the page is checking the login even if one wasn't supplied.  So if the file has a blank line or reading the file in any way interprets a line as being blank then a blank login will succeed.

Wrap the logic in something that checks if an attempt was posted:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  // your foreach loop
}
```

Or alternatively check if the posted values themselves are blank before comparing them.

---

Additionally, this is going to cause problems when trying to compare to a hashed password:

```
$password == $_POST['password']
```

You're going to need to hash the user input the same way the original was hashed before performing the comparison.